# Iterador Java | Incrementar dentro de uma sentinela

Tags: java, listener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            i++;
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            imagem.setIcon(icon);

            frame.add(imagem, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
}
});
```

Tenho um array de imagens, e o objetivo é sempre que carregar no botão (evento), o iterador i incrementa o seu valor em uma unidade e mudo de imagem.

Mas quando chego ao final do array (quando não existir imagens), ele dá me erro e bloqueia o programa. Sei que tenho de fazer um if(files.lenght) mas não sei bem onde o meter. Alguém me pode ajudar? Obrigado

Comment: O que é que você quer fazer? Contar quantas vezes o usuário clicou no botão?

Comment: Onde está o incremento no código? Por acaso você não está estourando o tamanho do array? Adicione um [mcve] editando a pergunta.

Comment: estou estourando sim, editei o post. A condição if é que está me a baralhar

Comment: Adicione a pilha de erros também.

Comment: @jbueno quando chegar ao final do tamanho do array quero que não de erro, e que lance uma excepção por exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas verifique se o indíce existe antes de tentar acessá-lo.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    i++;

    if(i < files.length()){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
        imagem.setIcon(icon);    
        frame.add(imagem, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    } else {
        //fazer alguma coisa
    }
}});
```

Obs.: Não dá pra entender muito bem o que você quer fazer. Isso vai funcionar, mas talvez não devesse ser feito assim, se você der mais detalhes posso melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Sinceramente é isso mesmo, descobri agora que o meu workspace estava a ser reescrito por isso é que estava a dar erro. Muito obrigado!